# Does adding linked text to a Quick Part and saving it automatically update it?

Tags: microsoft-word

I’m getting used to linking text from another Word document to a specific document and am curious to know if I saved the linked text as a quick part would it update anytime I decide to include it in the document? Is there any caveats? Do I need to save the text to the Normal Template?

Comment: Honestly, whenever you have a question of whether something will work or not, the best thing is that you try it out yourself, especially since you seem to have the skillset for it. This will be a way better learning experience than someone else telling you if it works or not.

Comment: Where can building blocks be stored? My writing: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks AutoText Fields: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoText_Fields